# Getting an error when installing the Google plus Package in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

[image]

I am trying to install google plus package but it is giving an error like above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Fix you problem - your app needs to have its Target Framework set to Android 7.0 (API Level 24) or higher to install it.

You can change it in Project Options -> General -> Target Framework.